# VBA Function only works for one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that takes one argument. The goal of the function is to look for a match (to the inputted argument) in the "Data" sheet Column B and then return the corresponding cell in Column F (times some factor I'm using). I want this function to be able to work on all sheets. Unfortunately it only seems to work on the Data sheet. For example, if I type "=CPOST(B18)" in a random cell on the Analyzer sheet, I get a "#Value!" error.

I've googled this and searched on SO and still not found anything. This is the first time I have asked a question on this site, despite getting tons of answers from here already. Thank you all.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function CPost(rng As Range)

' find the date in the data sheet from column 2 (B)
' sum the prior 21 abs values from column 6 (F)
' take the sum * factor * 100
' return that total as output

Dim LR As Integer

Set sh1 = Sheets("Analyzer")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Data")
Set sh3 = Sheets("Notes")

LR = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 3 To LR
    y = Cells(x, 2).Value
    If y = rng Then
        Set xx = Cells(x + 1, 6).Resize(21, 1)
        yy = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(xx)
        zz = yy * 5 * 100
        CPost = zz
    End If
Next x

End Function
```

UPDATE:

Based on all your responses below, which I really appreciate, I have copied my code from Module4 to ThisWorkbook. I removed Module4 (ht Dirk). I added Worksheet qualifiers to my ranges (ht BruceTimScott). I am now getting a "#NAME?" error when I try to type the formula in any Sheet in the Workbook. Here is the new code. I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious:

```
Public Function CPost(rng As Range)

' find the date in the data sheet from column 2 (B)
' sum the prior 21 abs values from column 6 (F)
' take the sum * factor * 100
' return that total as output

With Sheets("Data")

Dim LR As Integer

LR = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 3 To LR
    y = Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, 2).Value
    If y = rng Then
        Set xx = Worksheets("Data").Cells(x + 1, 6).Resize(21, 1)
        yy = .Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(xx)
        zz = yy * 5 * 100
        CPost = zz
    End If
Next x

End With

End Function
```

Comment: Is the code in a separate module or is it attached to the sheet?

Comment: It is in "Module4" under VBAProject(abc.xlsm)

Comment: You are using `Cells()` without any worksheet qualifier, so they will always refer to the *Activesheet* - this may give unexpected results.  You need to qualify every range reference with a worksheet object.

Comment: To further add to what @TimWilliams stated, you do this when setting `LR`, you just need to qualify the other instances of `Cells` with their correct worksheet.

Comment: I believe I added the qualifiers correctly. I'm still getting a naming error. I feel like I'm making a small mistake somewhere. Ty @TimWilliams & Scott

Comment: Alright friends, I added the qualifiers per @TimWilliams and co. suggestions. Once I added the code BACK to module4 it appears to work across all worksheets. So it seems that the code was acceptable in Module4, but needed the worksheets qualifier. I believe Tim's answer is correct to the best of my minimal VBA knowledge.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `Public Function CPost(rng As Range)` by `Public Function CPost(rng As Excel.Range)` in the function definition.